# Retry failed downloads (using multiple workers) and check the parent if multiple urls with the same parent fail

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.8

I'm creating a download worker using queues.

```
class Item:
  url: str
  download_path: str
  is_downloaded: bool
```

The worker code:

```
SENTINEL = "END"

 def download_item(to_download: Queue, downloaded: Queue):
        item: Item = to_download.get()
        while not (item == SENTINEL):
            try:
                response = request.urlopen(item.url)
            except error.HTTPError as e:
                item = to_download.get()
                continue
            item = write_to_file(item.download_path, content=response.read())
            downloaded_q.put(item)
            item = to_download.get()
        to_download.put(SENTINEL)
```

I want to introduce a retry mechanism and besides that a check parent folder mechanism.
For example:

```
bam/a - fail 
ram/s - ok
bam/c - fail
bam/d - fail
```

If more than count(2 files) that have "bam" as parent fail, check if the parent exist.
If the parent doesn't exist all the next urls that come from the queue and have "bam" in them automatically fail without trying to download.

The complexity is created by the fact that are more workers:

```
 with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=50) as executor:
            executor.submit(download_item, to_download_q, downloaded_q)
```

I'm looking for a solution, code or pseudo-code to approach this problem. Also I can't use third party packages in the environment.

Comment: How do you understand who the `parent` / `children` are?

Comment: child is a file that can be download, and the parent is folder that can be navigated to see the files.

Comment: I mean can you share list of `urls` or list of `Item` instances?